# Dealing with multi argument opcodes for interpreter

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am working on a simple interpreter to learn more about how they work.

I have a couple of aspects I am uncertain about.

How should I deal with opcodes of varying arguments?

I could have something like:

```
void execute(int opcode, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, Machine m);
```

However this:

```
-Limits me to 3 args
-Forces me to supply dummy args for opcodes taking less args
```

What are way (s) that interpreters normally deal with this?

I could ofcourse push an array of int, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the varargs notation.

Define your method as such:

```
void execute(int opcode, Machine m, int... args);
```

and now you can work with `args` like an array of ints (`int[]`).

This means that all these notations will work:

```
execute(opcode, m, arg1);
execute(opcode, m, arg1, arg2);
execute(opcode, m, arg1, arg2, arg3);
execute(opcode, m, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
```

Important note: if you have two parameters of the same type and one of them is a varargs then you will have to put the varargs behind the singular one to prevent ambiguation.

As Elliot correctly points out: it has to be the last parameter as well when there are others.

Comment: One clarification, only the last argument can be variable length.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: good point, I thought it only mattered with variables of the same type.

Comment: That may be true in other languages. Another note, varargs makes the args entirely optional... so `execute (opcode, m);` is also valid.